# How to make node + expressjs application work with browser back forward history?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a simple login logout system like so:

```
exports.login = function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    db.users.find({email: email, password: password}, function(err, users) {
        if (users.length === 0) {
            res.render('home', {
                title: siteTitle,
                loginError: 'true',
                errorMsg: 'Wrong login credentials'
            });
        } else {
            req.session.username = email;
            res.redirect('/main');
        }
    });
};

exports.logout = function(req, res) {
    // delete the session variable
    delete req.session.username;
    // redirect user to homepage
    res.redirect('/');
};
```

Here are the bindings:

```
app.get('/', store.home);
app.post('/', store.home);

app.get('/main', store.main);
app.post('/main', store.main);

app.post('/login', store.login);
app.get('/login', store.login);

app.get('/logout', store.logout);
app.post('/logout', store.logout);
```

So I have the pages:

1. `/` (only goes here if user is not logged in, otherwise redirects to `/main`)
2. `/login` (immediately redirects to `/main` or `/`)
3. `/main` (goes here only if user is logged in, otherwise redirects to `/`).

Use case:

1. Goto `/`.
2. Login
3. You now get redirected to `/main`.
4. Hit the browser back button.
5. **You are now in `/` as if you never logged in! Why?**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use session to determine the state of the user and then redirect him accordingly.

[nodejs-and-express-sessions](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions)

Comment: I am using session as you can see from the code I've pasted. It seems to work fine when I open pages normally via the address bar or link in my web app. But it is using the browser back/forward buttons that is messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

This a general problem as browser caches the pages in history.

There are several ways to address the issue. It's covered [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/549347/Browser-Back-Button-Issue-After-Logout) in detail.

Comment: Thanks! How do I disable automatic caching in ExpressJS?